# Problem modeling capacitor bank for Three Phase Induction Motor

Tags: capacitor, three-phase, induction-motor, capacitor-banks

I'm currently working on a simulation in Simulink and I encountered a problem. I'm using a capacitor bank to improve the voltage drop at the output voltage of the motor. The problem is the capacitor bank doesn't work unless I use a very high value for the Capacitive Reactive Power ( in theory, 500kVAr should be enough to make a difference, but for one capacitor bank I have to use the 3000KVar to get the an even voltage tension without any major value drops).

[image: General schematic:]

[image: Model for one capacitor bank]

[image: Parameters of the motor]

[image: Voltage values with capacitor banks connected]

The value of the resistance at the input of the motor in 0.95 ohm.
Torque input for the motor is 42940, step time is set to 10.
The motor is powered from a three phase system, 6000V 50Hz.
The parameters of the motor are from a data sheet(excluding stator, rotor resistance and inductance, mutual inductance, friction factor). I cannot manage to find the explination why the capacitor banks don't influence the voltage drop displayed in the scope. My opinion is there is a problem with one of the parameters ( the resistance used at powering the motor, or one parameters from motor).

Comment: I don't have Matlab, but it looks like the `2x250` block has 3000 V LL, while the motor 6000. Try adding current sensors after the capacitors, and compare the input with the output, maybe it tells something.

Comment: It's seems like one current phase is very small when using both capacitor banks connected. With only one, the current spike is still present.

Comment: Does the sim start with any initial conditions such as a starting RPM, or voltage on the capacitors?